# Renaming multiple csv files

Tags: python, renaming

I have the following problem: in my directories I have numerous folders which all contain csv files with names in the following format:

```
00000562834-2018-07-27-file-8.csv
```

In order to make these files available on scale in python, I have to insert the name in the form of a formula ("xxxxxxxxxxxx-year-month-day-file-hour"). However, the first digits (in this case 00000562834) are random, so I cannot create a code that uses all files automatically.

Hence my question: Does anybody know how I can remove these first 12 digits in all my csv.files? Changing all manually would not scale, unfortunately.

Comment: Is there just one file per date / hour? If you remove the first part of the file names, wouldn't you get name collisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using pathlib and the [`rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) method.

```
from pathlib import Path
rootfolder = '/home/nicolaso/foo/bar/'  # example

for f in Path(rootfolder).rglob('*-file-*.csv'):
  new_name = f.name.split('-', 1)[1]
  f.rename(f.with_name(new_name))
```

If you don't actually want to rename the files, you can just process them in the for loop anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex. `re.sub`

```
import re
s = "00000562834-2018-07-27-file-8.csv"
print( re.sub(r"\d{11}-", "", s) )
```

**Output:**

```
2018-07-27-file-8.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import glob
import re

for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    os.rename(file, re.sub(r"\d+-", "", file))
```