# Renaming csv files according to some contents inside the csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, time-series

I have many csv files in one subfolder, say data. Each of these .csv files contain a **date** column.

```
430001.csv, 43001(1).csv,43001(2).csv,..........,43001(110).csv etc.
```

I want to rename all the files in folder according  to the date inside column of csv file.

**Desired output:**

```
430001-1980.csv, 43001-1981.csv,43001-1985.csv,..........,43001-2010.csv etc.
```

I tried to follow the steps advised in :
[Renaming multiple csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574087/renaming-multiple-csv-files)

Still could not get the desired output.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code/attempts? And where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: Please provide also a sample of a .csv content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through them, extract the date to create a new filename, and then save it.

```
# packages to import
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import sys

data_p = "Directory with your data"
output_p = "Directory where you want to save your output"
retval = os.getcwd() 
print (retval) # see in which folder you are

os.chdir(data_p) # move to the folder with your data
os.getcwd()

filenames = sorted(glob.glob('*.csv'))
fnames = list(filenames) # get the names of all your files
#print(fnames) 

for f in range(len(fnames)):
    print(f'fname: {fnames[f]}\n')
    pfile = pd.read_csv(fnames[f], delimiter=",") # read in file

    #extract filename
    filename = fnames[f]
    parts = filename.split(".") # giving you the number in file name and .csv
    only_id = parts[0].split("(") # if there is a bracket included 

    # get date from your file
    filedate = pfile["date"][0] # assuming this is on the first row
    filedate = str(filedate)

    # get new filename
    newfilename = only_id[0]+"-"+filedate+parts[1]

    # save your file (don't put a slash at the end of your directories on top)
    pfile.to_csv(output_p+"/"+newfilename, index = False, header = True)
```

Comment: Dear Clarius333 , Thank you very much. My problem is fixed with minor revision on codes as per own convenience... Thanks a lot!